# Fragments vs Activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

In the app I have written, I have almost entirely used activities--other than an instance when I have swipable views--as opposed to fragments, and I have been wondering if this is "bad coding practice." Each of my views are fairly light, and I have had no problem passing data through the activities. If I were to use fragments, I was wondering what the best way to go about this is. Is it best to instantiate all of the fragments you are going to use at once and use a place holder in your activity's layout for the current fragment being displayed? Or should you define all fragments you are going to use statically in your layout file? I am just wondering what route I should take before converting almost a month's worth of code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One of the major advantages of Fragments are that they can be re-used. They can easily be added again and again in multiple activities, in slightly new ways.

Similarly ActionBar allows you to easily use fragments to switch between tabs

ViewPager with a FragmentPagerAdapter can be used to create swipe interfaces. The FragmentPagerAdapter code is much cleaner than a regular adapter, and it controls instantiations of the individual fragments.

It is also easier to pass data to fragments.

The main point is what is cleaner? Are your components re-used in multiple places? These are the main ideas to think about. The other points are imo bonuses.